# Python: How to total of the scores for all the tweets in a region divided by the number of tweets (Lots of info provided,)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, subprocess, pycharm

I have two files, one containing over 200 tweets, and another containing key words and values.
a typical tweet looks like:

```
[41.923916200000001, -88.777469199999999] 6 2011-08-28 19:24:18 My life is a moviee.
```

and the keywords look something like

```
love,10
like,5
best,10
hate,1
```

With the two numbers at the beginning of the tweet, I use that to determine what region the tweet was made in (shown below in my code). & For each individual tweet (each line in the file), depending on the number of keywords in the tweet, I add them, divided by the total of values associated with them (per tweet) which gives me the score. My question is,
how would I be able to total the scores for all the tweets in a region and divide that by the number of tweets in that region? Below, where I put happynessTweetScore, is how I calculated the score for the individual tweets in the file (each line) that actually contain keywords. For this part, I'm **not sure how to add all the values depending on the region, and divide them depending on the number of tweets in that region**? like should I add them to a list depending on their region then add?? i don't know.
I divided the tweets into four regions (latitude, long) using these values (rectangle) ALL THE WAY at the bottom of the code:

```
p1 = (49.189787, -67.444574) 
p2 = (24.660845, -67.444574) 
p3 = (49.189787, -87.518395) 
p4 = (24.660845, -87.518395) 
p5 = (49.189787, -101.998892) 
p6 = (24.660845, -101.998892) 
p7 = (49.189787, -115.236428)
p8 = (24.660845, -115.236428) 
p9 = (49.189787, -125.242264)
p10 = (24.660845, -125.242264) 

from collections import Counter
try:
    keyW_Path = input("Enter file named keywords: ")
    keyFile = open(keyW_Path, "r")
except IOError:
    print("Error: file not found.")
    exit()
# Read the keywords into a list
keywords = {}
wordFile = open('keywords.txt', 'r')
for line in wordFile.readlines():
    word = line.replace('\n', '')
    if not(word in keywords.keys()): #Checks that the word doesn't already exist.
        keywords[word] = 0 # Adds the word to the DB.
wordFile.close()
# Read the file name from the user and open the file.
try:
    tweet_path = input("Enter file named tweets: ")
    tweetFile = open(tweet_path, "r")
except IOError:
    print("Error: file not found.")
    exit()
#Calculating Sentiment Values
with open('keywords.txt') as f:
    sentiments = {word: int(value) for word, value in (line.split(",") for line in f)}

with open('tweets.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        values = Counter(word for word in line.split() if word in sentiments)
        if not values:
            continue
keyW = ["love", "like", "best", "hate", "lol", "better", "worst", "good", "happy", "haha", "please", "great", "bad", "save", "saved", "pretty", "greatest", 'excited', 'tired', 'thanks', 'amazing', 'glad', 'ruined', 'negative', 'loving', 'sorry', 'hurt', 'alone', 'sad', 'positive', 'regrets', 'God']
with open('tweets.txt') as oldfile, open('newfile.txt', 'w') as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:
        if any(word in line for word in keyW):
            newfile.write(line)
def score(tweet):
    total = 0
    for word in tweet:
        if word in sentiments:
            total += 1
    return total
def total(score):
    sum = 0
    for number in score:
        if number in values:
            sum += 1
#Classifying the regions
class Region:
    def __init__(self, lat_range, long_range):
        self.lat_range = lat_range
        self.long_range = long_range
    def contains(self, lat, long):
        return self.lat_range[0] <= lat and lat < self.lat_range[1] and\
               self.long_range[0] <= long and long < self.long_range[1]
eastern = Region((24.660845, 49.189787), (-87.518395, -67.444574))
central = Region((24.660845, 49.189787), (-101.998892, -87.518395))
mountain = Region((24.660845, 49.189787), (-115.236428, -101.998892))
pacific = Region((24.660845, 49.189787), (-125.242264, -115.236428))

eastScore = 0
centralScore = 0
pacificScore = 0
mountainScore = 0
happyScoreE = 0

for line in open('newfile.txt'):
    line = line.split(" ")
    lat = float(line[0][1:-1]) #Stripping the [ and the ,
    long = float(line[1][:-1])  #Stripping the ]
    if eastern.contains(lat, long):
        eastScore += score(line)
    elif central.contains(lat, long):
        centralScore += score(line)
    elif mountain.contains(lat, long):
        mountainScore += score(line)
    elif pacific.contains(lat, long):
        pacificScore += score(line)
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: How many of these do you anticipate processing, how quickly do you need these stats (one-time batch analysis or are you going to make this part of ETL, and how comfortable are you with matrices / databases / KVS?  This can be done in many ways, and my preference would be to do using Redis, but if that is new to you, there are other ways to skin this...

Comment: @ToddCurry Do you understand what my question was asking?? I wasnt sure if I was clear enough. And Im just trying to do this in the simplest way possible.. I havent used Redis before though.

Comment: What is the third number in the tweet data line?  The one just after the closing square bracket.

Comment: @James Thank you for pointing that out. I forgot to mention the only relevant information is the numbers within the brackets, and the tweet which starts after the time. Just ignore anything in betweem

Comment: Yep, it makes sense.  Each line is regional, all terms in a line are scored, all scores are added to regional totals, as are record counts.  At the end, you want the total score per region to be divided by the total count of terms for the region.  If you are testing with 200 tweets, I'll offer an easier solution; if this is the start of a "parse the Twitter firehose" endeavor, you will want a bigger boat..

Comment: Are you open to using Pandas?  This could really help your filtering problem.

Comment: @ToddCurry its around 1000+ tweets and yes thats exactly what i need to do!! Im so relieved I was clear

Comment: @James Ive never heard of Pandas before, im relatively new to python

Comment: Pandas is a module that allows you to create and use data frames. A data frame allows you to perform the sorting, merging, filtering, and aggregation steps you are trying to code by hand.  Did you install Python by itself, or as part of an installation package such as Anaconda?

Comment: Python (well PycharmEDU) by itself @James

Comment: @James is right. Redis is an alternative, too for making this simpler.  Stylistically, you are doing a lot in this program.  I would modularize and have on python script for assigning scores to the words that you read in from file 1, storing them in a structure that can then be called upon in script 2 when you parse the 1000+ tweets.  Redis is great for both that intermediate storage as well as the aggregation functions.

Comment: @ToddCurry Im not sure what Redis is or how to use it,  but when I was able to figure out how to do what is in my question, I was going to look through my program to see if there were ways I could make it more simple and easy to read. But I just want it to work first, and have what I need it to do, makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the two places I would work are on your line parsing and your score function.  Have score function return both a total score and a valid word count, so that you can keep track of both in your main block.  Right now you are not pulling the value associated with keywords back into your score function...

```
def score(tweet):
    total = 0   # don't need to do this, but I am a*al this way, too
    total_value = 0  # as I just said
    for word in tweet:
        word = word.lower()    # presuming your keywords are all in lower case
        if word in sentiments:
            total_value += sentiments[word]  # you have to pull the value back
            total_count += 1                 # and keep a running total
    return total_value, total_count
```

This would be called as it is currently called:

```
for line in open('newfile.txt'):
    line = line.split(" ")
    lat = float(line[0][1:-1]) #Stripping the [ and the ,
    long = float(line[1][:-1])  #Stripping the ]
    if eastern.contains(lat, long):
        line_score, line_count = score(line)
        eastScore += line_score
        eastCount += line_count
    elif central.contains(lat, long):
        line_score, line_count = score(line)
        centralScore += line_score
        centralCount += line_count
    elif mountain.contains(lat, long):
        line_score, line_count = score(line)
        mountainScore += line_score
        mountainCount += line_count
    elif pacific.contains(lat, long):
        line_score, line_count = score(line)
        pacificScore += line_score
        pacificCount += line_count
    else:
        continue
```

If your line parsing works, I'll leave it alone, but I prefer to be more explicit than cute with the tedium of data preparation.  Explicit makes sense at midnight, when you have to revisit the code; cute requires two cups of coffee.

```
for line in open('newfile.txt'):
    line = line.replace('[','')   # kill leading bracket
    text = line.split(']')       # split coords / words using trailing bracket
    coordinates = text[0].split(',')    # split coords on comma.... IIRC
    lat = float(coordinates[0].replace(' ',''))   # kill any spaces
    long = float(coordinates[1].replace(' ',''))  # ditto
    word_stream = text[1]  # this later is called via score(word_stream)
```

Comment: Does this method allow me to separate the totals/word counts for each region?

Comment: Oh, I cant change the tweets by the way, thats the format it has to stay in

Comment: Like would I then use if statements like: if tweet in eastern, eastScore = totalvalue/total count?

Comment: See above -- you would use the same code you have, just adjusting for the extra information coming back.